# my api data dont work with Postman (Unauthorized)

Tags: api, request, key, postman

Is someone know why i got unauthorization on postman. I got the key but it didnt work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The response message is telling you the exact headers you need to provide but are not providing.  You've obscured the header you are providing, but presumably what you've sent is a *value* for a header, not a *key* for a header.  The message is telling you the *keys*:

1. `x-app-id`
2. `x-app-key`

Those would go in the "KEY" column of the headers you provide, and the values for those headers would go in the "VALUE" column.  (The "DESCRIPTION" column is optional.)

The semantics of the word "key" appear to have confused you in this case.  The headers themselves are key/value pairs, and the "app key" you have is a value *called* an "app key".  The word "key" has two distinct meanings in this case.